# Can this jQuery animation code be made more elegant?

Tags: jquery, animation, refactoring

fairly new to jQuery, and i have come up with some animation code which works, but it looks very ugly.

```
function help() {

    $("#searchBox").click(function(){
        $('#search_text_1').stop(true,true).hide();
        $('#search_text_2').stop(true,true).hide();
        $('#search_text_3').stop(true,true).hide();
        $('#search_text_4').stop(true,true).hide();
        $('#search_text_5').stop(true,true).hide();
        $('#free_search_help_1').stop(true,true).hide();
        $('#free_search_help_2').stop(true,true).hide();
        $('#free_search_help_3').stop(true,true).hide();
        $('#free_search_help_4').stop(true,true).hide();
        $('#free_search_help_5').stop(true,true).hide();
  });

    $('#search_text_1').delay(1000).fadeIn(500).delay(4000).fadeOut(500, function() {
        $('#search_text_2').fadeIn(500).delay(4000).fadeOut(500, function() {
            $('#search_text_3').fadeIn(500).delay(4000).fadeOut(500, function() {
                $('#search_text_4').fadeIn(500).delay(4000).fadeOut(500, function() {
                    $('#search_text_5').fadeIn(500);
                });
            });
        });
    });

    $('#free_search_help_1').delay(1000).fadeIn(500).delay(4000).fadeOut(500, function() {
        $('#free_search_help_2').fadeIn(500).delay(4000).fadeOut(500, function() {
            $('#free_search_help_3').fadeIn(500).delay(4000).fadeOut(500, function() {
                $('#free_search_help_4').fadeIn(500).delay(4000).fadeOut(500, function() {
                    $('#free_search_help_5').fadeIn(500);
                });
            });
        });
    });

}
```

I am particularly concerned with the click function to stop the animations, seems a bit hacky to me. I did try calling .stop() on a class that was assigned to all the divs that were being animated, but this didn't seem to work (no errors).

I also tried:

```
$("div:animated").stop(true,true);
```

but this only worked if the click happened during the fades, and not the delays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the starts with selector `^=`[<sup>DOCS</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to get a list of the elements that start with your ids.  Then you can use a for loop and the `.eq()`[<sup>DOCS</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method to get the individual items in the list and conduct their animations accordingly.

[**Here's an example of the following.**](http://jsfiddle.net/gCSFV/)

```
function help() {
    var $st  = $('[id^="search_text_"]'),
        $fsh = $('[id^="free_search_help_"]');

    $("#searchBox").click(function() {
        $st.stop(true, true).hide();
        $fsh.stop(true, true).hide();
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < $st.length; i++) {
        var tDelay = 1000 + 5000*i;
        $st.eq(i).delay(tDelay).fadeIn(500).delay(4000).fadeOut(500);
        $fsh.eq(i).delay(tDelay).fadeIn(500).delay(4000).fadeOut(500);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not add a class to your search divs? 
That would be for sure the most elegant solution!
Then you would do this:

$("#searchBox").click(function(){
    $('.search_text').stop(true,true).hide();
    $('.free_search_help').stop(true,true).hide();
});

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to "search_text_?" elements and the "free_search_help_?" elements and use the class to "stop(true, true).hide()".

or use:

```
$('div[id^=search_text]'     ).stop(true, true).hide();
$('div[id^=free_search_help]').stop(true, true).hide();
```

or:

I would tidy up and optimise the code by first assigning variables to the relevant elements and then using those variables, rather getting jQuery to locate the elements each time. e.g.

```
var $s[6], $f[6], i = 1;

while (i < 6) {
    $s[i  ] = $('#search_text_'      + i);
    $f[i  ] = $('#free_search_help_' + i);
    $f[i  ].stop(true, true) hide();
    $s[i++].stop(true, true).hide();
}

$s[1].delay(....   etc.....
    $s[2].fadeIn(....    etc.....
        $s[3].fadeIn(....    etc.....
            $s[4].fadeIn(....    etc.....
                $s[5].fadeIn(....    etc....
```

Regards
       Neil